# input doesnt read spaces(_tscanf_s and wcscpy_s)

Tags: c, input, whitespace, tchar

This is my code,

```
_tprintf(_T("\nPlease set all fields"));
_tprintf(_T("\n Input Name: "));
_tscanf_s(L"%ls",inputHolder,length);
wcscpy_s(LC.NAME,length, inputHolder);
```

the problem is when I am inputting a name with space the program will think that the white space is a enter then it will skip to the next input.For example

( what i want, **Input Name: mj stack**)

( whats happening, **Input Name:mj  Category:stack**)

Help please, ps I am a noob.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  The `%s` conversion specifier is defined to stop at the first white space.  If you want a different meaning, you need to use a different conversion specifier.  Maybe you should be reading lines with `fgets()`?  Maybe you should be using a scanset such as `%[^\n]` to read the data.  It's hard to be sure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I used %ls not %s. afaik %ls stands for long string like %i stands for int. im so confused, anyway thanks for response.